# .NET CMS. Shall we build or use existing one

Tags: .net, angularjs, content-management-system, umbraco

**Hi All,**

In a new project we have a requirement to build a CMS. As this is big organization and requirement is designed a CMS system with SOA which can provide common publishing (view) for various applications. Some of the applications need to develop, some already there in .NET (very slow) and some of them are in classic ASP which needs to migrate to .NET.
CMS is very first application which need to develop. So question is as below:

**1)Shall we develop and new CMS from scratch (using MVC, Angular etc.) or shall we use something existing e.g. Umbraco or Dotnetnuke**

We are in initial stage and exploring options. Of course using Umbraco will save time but what type of limitations can be there in future? Is it easily expandable?

Anyone has experience using .NET related CMS?

Cheers

Comment: You should ask this question instead on http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ and provide the specific features you need.

Comment: I recommend NOT using sitecore. Ever.

Comment: Thanks Both. Have not planned using sitecore as we are using .NET stack for our development. So dotnet related CMS Umbraco, DotNetNuke (DNN), Kentico, Sitefinity, mojoPortal are could be options. Still not sure what to do. Build CMS or use existing one and add custom features. I put same question on softwarerecs.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2):

I use Orchard and I really like it for the most part - it's highly extensible and built on modern technologies.  However, I do think it has a very steep learning curve  if you plan to do deep development/customization, so be prepared for some learning, especially if you don't have a lot of experience with MVC, C# dynamics, lambdas...

Orchard also has a pretty good theming engine and built in support for Web API, which can provide some great services.

I worked briefly with DotNetNuke and that was one of the worst development experiences I've had, would never go back to that ever.

Answer (score 0):

I would add Orchard to your list of starting points to look at if you wish to use the .NET stack.

http://orchardproject.net/